# Testing a VF parameter is getting as Null?

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

I have a VF page that is used for rendering a PDF. All the fields are `apex:outputText` and getting the values from a form-submission-VF page. 
I am using just a constructor to set the values for this PDF rendering page. Like this:

```
public class PDFViewerCtrl {
 public String fNameText {get; set;} 

  public PDFViewerCtrl(){
    fNameText = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('fName');   
  }  
}
```

PDFViewerPage

```
<label>First Name: </label>
<apex:outputText value="{!fNameText}"> </apex:outputText><br/>
```

Test class:
PDFViewerCtrlTest

```
static testMethod void testPDFViewerPageCtrl(){
    String firstName = 'TestFirstName';
    PDFViewerCtrl ctrl = new PDFViewerCtrl();
    PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/PDFViewerPage');
    Test.setCurrentPage(pg);
    pg.getParameters().put('fNameText', firstName);
    System.assertEquals('TestFirstName', ctrl.fNameText); 
}
```

Test failed with the error message:

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: TestFirstName, Actual: null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instantiate `PDFViewerCtrl` after setting the parameters in the `visualforce page`. As you are creating an instance of `PDFViewerCtrl` first and then setting the visualforce page parameter it won't set the values in the `constructor`. The constructor is called when an instance is created of the class and when your instance is created, it won't find any page parameters hence it is giving you `null` value. You can refer [Testing Custom Controllers and Controller Extensions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm)

And one more issue with your code is, you are getting the parameter by `fName` key in your constructor whereas you are passing parameter with key as `fNameText`.

Your test class should be something like this

```
static testMethod void testPDFViewerPageCtrl(){
    String firstName = 'TestFirstName';
    PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/PDFViewerPage');
    Test.setCurrentPage(pg);
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('fName', firstName);
    PDFViewerCtrl ctrl = new PDFViewerCtrl();
    System.assertEquals('TestFirstName', ctrl.fNameText); 
}
```

Comment: Hi Vijay, thanks for your time. Even after replicating your strategy, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Updated the answer, there was an issue with the parameter name in your test class.

Comment: Awesome. Yeah, I was very certain I am missing something that is very naive.